# PyQt table row background colour based on cell value with SQlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

`hi, How to change row color based on the Yes/No column. I am using sqlite as a database.
Below is my code where i want to change color of cells

[My PyQt table =====>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZobW.png)
[SQlite Database ===>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g492e.png)
[Expecting result all 1's to green in PyQt5 table widget ====>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOezF.png)`

```
def check_table(self):
    try:
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Curing ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 100")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        col = [i[0] for i in cur.description]

        if result:
            self.tb_ch_table.setRowCount(len(result))
            self.tb_ch_table.setColumnCount(len(col))

            self.tb_ch_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col)

            # self.tb_ch_table.styleSheet("alternate-background-color: Lightgrey;background-color: white;")
            
            for row, item in enumerate(result):
                for column, data in enumerate(item):
                    self.tb_ch_table.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

        else:
            return
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.check_table)
    except Exception as e:
        self.frame_ch.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.show_ch_msg(msg=str(e))
```

Comment: Use an item delegate and override `initStyleOption`, then just change the background brush based on the index value.

Comment: I've already suggested what you could do, so please take your time, patiently and carefully study the documentation and do your own research to understand how you can solve your problem, then eventually [edit] your question or post another showing us your attempts. Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a tutorial website: what you're asking is not immediate nor enough engaging to create an answer that would guide through the whole procedure. If you properly study the documentation of the objects you're using, you'll eventually find out what you need.

Comment: Also, remember that we expect a minimum research effort on questions, and a valid code to start with (see: [mre]), which is not your case, since we have no way to know what (or when) `check_table()` is called. Not to mention that arbitrarily creating a singleShot QTimer is certainly not a good idea unless you have complete control on when and how that function is called. You may end up with recursion, unnecessarily occupying system resources.